# How to manage Distributed transaction using spring and J2EE (EJB) CMT

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

I have a situation to integrate two independent systems. One is using J2EE,EJBs and other is Spring based. Now the problem is both the systems can call methods of each other and i want to manage transactions as well. I am not sure how to coordinate both applications transaction managers as both are using different one (Spring and EJB).

Any one has an idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, both applications should use Extended transactions (XA transactions) on DataSource level (and for other resources such as Message Queues, JCA adapters or whatever resources you use in application).

Method calls should be done through Remote EJB call or web services that use WS-AtomicTransaction to handle transaction boundaries. If you do not want to change your architecture to add Remote EJBs, your best bet is to use web services with WS-AT that use XA transactions under the hood.

Comment: This makes sense,i am also using web services to call the methods from spring based application.But i am not sure how to add support for WS-AT here, cause it uses Restlet.

Comment: I did not work with Restlet library, but as far as I can see, it does not have support to plug into global transaction coordinator, but again, I might be wrong...